# How do I adjust a slider to show the current brightness level on Mac OSX using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, slider, brightness

I have created a slider that allows me to control the brightness on my Mac. I'm trying to make sure the slider accurately represents the current brightness level. If I change the brightness via the keyboard, I want the slider to reflect the new level.

Right now the slider will show me the current brightness level, but only after I click the slider. Furthermore, I cannot change the brightness from the slider.

```
@IBAction func brightnessSlider(sender: NSSlider) {
    verticalSlider.floatValue = getBrightnessLevel()
    setBrightnessLevel(sender.floatValue)
}
```

If I remove the line trying to get the brightness, I can adjust the brightness level from the slider, but it always starts out as maxed out.

How can I have the slider be both adjustable and always reflect the brightness level?

Also, [here's a link](https://github.com/spearskw/BrightnessMenu) to the full source if it's helpful.

EDIT:
I'm able to have the slider display the correct brightness when I click on the menu with the following code, but it still doesn't update while it's open. Also, updating while it's closed seems like a bad idea.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("updateBrightnessSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)` seems to work. Thus, the full snippet is as follows:

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateBrightnessSlider"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

func updateBrightnessSlider() {
    verticalSlider.floatValue = getBrightnessLevel()
}
```